# Fuzziness of text in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, font-smoothing

In Chrome, texts looks amazing on my monitor (Dell u3014).  But in Microsoft Office and Windows folders, they are fuzzy.  How to fix.

Btw,

I already tried playing with ClearType and tried using the MacType program which didn't make any difference that I can tell.  Playing with DPI scaling in properties for windows programs shouldn't be the problem since texts look gorgeous in Chrome.

Anyone else have anymore ideas?

Additional Info:

Fonts actually look AWESOME in Chrome. If I could get it to that level everywhere, I would be a very happy person.

Sadly, texts look blurry in Microsoft office applications like Word which I use A LOT and the icone text in Windows desktop and folders which I also use a lot.

Comment: First eliminate the obvious, are you running at your monitor's native resolution in Windows 10? Secondly, does all text in Windows 10 looks fuzzy or only certain app or dialog box looks fuzzy?

Comment: Chrome doesn't support dpi scaling, that's why it looks bad on hidpi displays and you have to zoom the web page in

Comment: Luu, I think you misunderstood my post.  I have a hi dpi display and the fonts in Chrome look awesome.  I can zoom in and out and the fonts always look awesome.  It's running at native resolution, of course.  It just seems like it looks good ONLY in Chrome.