# Windows display scaling looks pixelated sometimes

Tags: windows, windows-10, resolution

I have a high DPI 3840x2160 screen which I have set to 200% scaling in the windows display settings (this is on Windows 10 version 1703).  A lot of times text looks nice and crisp but sometimes stuff gets scaled up in a pixelated way (screenshot below).  Certain programs can look good and others bad at the same time and even restarting a "bad" program doesn't fix it.  Rebooting does fix it though.  It seems to correlate to do with changing resolutions and/or adding / removing external monitors but doesn't resolve even when only this display is what's being used and the resolution is for sure 3840x2160.  Is there some way to prevent this or fix it without rebooting?

Here are some screenshots / photos to see what I'm talking about:
[image]
[image]

Comment: this is a known issue with Windows 10. Any apps that use the new hidpi API may result in blurry text https://superuser.com/q/947391/241386 https://superuser.com/q/1231598/241386 https://lifehacker.com/fix-blurry-fonts-in-windows-10-with-this-utility-1734246822

Answer (score 0):

DPI scaling has to be supported by the individual programs that are using it. In the early days of retina I also had trouble getting Chrome for example to properly scale, the failback option is to just make everything bigger resulting in the pixelated text you are seeing. Have you tried updating your software to the most recent versions?

Comment: If they work fine after rebooting, wouldn't it not be the apps themselves?

Answer (score 0):

if this is still a problem for some users, try adjusting the **Sharpness** settings of your monitor, most likely 40% will be perfect.

remember, you must adjust these setting from your monitor's OSD (On Screen Display)